# Maximum update depth exceeded error reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to redirect when property is null ReactJS but I get an error stating

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

i don't see infinite loop here, can anyone help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {userProfile} from '../../actions/profile'
import {loadUser} from '../../actions/auth';
import Alert from '../layout/Alert';
class Dashboard extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.userProfile();
    }
    onSubmit=(formvalue) => {
        console.log(formvalue);
    }

    render() {
        if(!this.props.profile.userProfile){
            return <Redirect to="/" />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Alert />
                Hello
            </div>
        )

    }

}
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        auth: state.auth,
        profile: state.profile
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{userProfile,loadUser})(Dashboard);
```

Comment: have you try to  remove <Alert /> and does the error still happen ?

Comment: yes.  I have deleted <Alert />. Alert is static component does'not have any state right now.